# How to unzip a file to the exact path using 7z.exe?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running the following command line,

```
7z.exe e "d:/file.zip"
```

it unzip the file in the same path.

But, my requirement is , i need to set the path where it need to extract the file.

for example,

i need to extract `d:/file.zip` in `c:/folder/`

i tried running the command,

```
7z.exe e "d:/file.zip" "c:/folder/"
```

it fails, So, pls help me guys. So much of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run 7z.exe -? to see all available parameters. Use -o to specify a folder where the zip file should be extracted:

```
7z.exe x c:\temp\temp.zip -oc:\temp\myfolder
```